# Something about cache-algorithm

Tags: caching, optimization, cpu

Assuming we have some array located in some fixed memory address that being frequently accessed and updated (updating at a much much lower frequency compared to the frequency of accessing), can modern CPUs in general cache the entire array if the size of the array is small? Can updating/accessing of the array be accomplished entirely in cache instead of main memory storage?

Based on my past experience, it is likely the case for several Intel CPUs I tested, but I need some more details about the caching algorithm (which is so hard to find for any remotely recent CPU models) to develop my algorithm optimally.

Answer (score 0):

Writes can be either write-back or write-through, depending on the specific CPU in question.  Most modern CPUs support write-back.

Multiple reads *may* be done from cache, depending on several factors including

- What other processing is happening on the computer (something else may evict your array from cache).
- Whether multiple cores are accessing the array.  Each core typically has its own cache.

For information about Intel cache architectures, see

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol  (Intel CPUs)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOESI_protocol (AMD64 CPUs)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MERSI_protocol (PowerPC CPUs)

Comment: So we cannot use cache like a fast memory buffer since any writting ops there will result in an expensive memory-writting, which means CPU's cache cannot do  what nvidia GPU's cache can, thats too bad.

Comment: @user1748356: I corrected that statement.  Most modern CPUs support write-back cache in addition to write-through.

Comment: But can the cache to memory writting occurs at the same time as the cache accessing? I mean, an operation is copying data x from cache to main memory while another operation is copying data x from cache to register etc, both operations are taking place at the same time/parallely so the data-accessing operation dont need to wait until the memory-writing is finished?